# .htaccess multi domain using

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I want to load defined folders into my website from same system, now I need to know how I can get a folder from a domain if I type "domain.dk" its load "theme/domain.dk/javascript/ and if I type "domain.com" its load "theme/domain.com/javascript/" folder to use.

```
RewriteRule ^Javascript?$     /theme/{HTTP_HOST}/javascript
```

This is my .htaccess code, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at the right-hand side: are you missing a % before

```
{HTTP_HOST}
```

like

```
%{HTTP_HOST}
```

??